# python script ambiguous error message

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am using jupiter notebooks and root with C++ kernel in order to create some interactive documentation. The documentation includes some histograms and other graphs, so I am using the magic %%jsroot in order to make the graphs interactive. The magic is produsing javascript instead of just images so they can be interactive.

Everything works until I try to use nbconvert to turn the notebooks into a pdf file. Since the javascript can not be transfered to pdf I am using a script to remove the cell where I call the %%jsroot and re-run the notebook in order to create the images.
The %%jsroot comand is called in a separate cell.
This is my script:

import string
    import sys
    infilename = sys.argv[1]
    outfilename = sys.argv[2]

```
f = open(infilename)
lines = f.readlines()
f.close()
text = "".join(lines)

true=True
false=False

nbj = eval(text)

cells = nbj["cells"]

newcells=[]
jscount = 0
mustdecrement = False
for cell in cells:
   if cell["source"][0] == "%%jsroot on":
     mustdecrement = True
     jscount = 1
     continue
   else:
     if mustdecrement:
       cell["execution_count"] -= 1
     newcells.append(cell)
nbj["cells"] = newcells

if jscount == 1:
   newnb = open(outfilename,"w")
   newnb.write(str(nbj))
   newnb.close()
```

It gives me the error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>    File "removeJS.py", line 28, in 
>      cell["execution_count"] -= 1
>   KeyError: 'execution_count'

Any ideas what this could be?

Comment: Side note: doing `eval(text)` is not a good way of loading JSON. We provide [the nbformat package](http://nbformat.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html) to load and write notebook files.

Comment: Hello Thomas, Thanks a lot for the answer it is helpful. I used the nbformat in order to read and succesfully write a notebook to a new ipynb file. My next problem is that I do not really understand how to edit the dictionarry before writing it in a file. Is there some documentation on how to access and edit the cells?

Comment: I don't think there are good docs, but the notebook object you get from nbformat follows the JSON structure of the notebook, so `nb.cells` will be a list of cells.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this one (simple logic error). 
The execution_count property did not exist on the markdown cells so it was not found.